# H2 fails when altering table for 2 foreign keys (MYSQL syntax)

Tags: mysql, h2

Working on adding testing to an existing project that uses Flyway. The tables are in Versioned flyway files, so they can't change, but trying to figure out what the cause of this basic use-case is.

```sql
CREATE TABLE table1
(
    id LONG PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT
);

CREATE TABLE table2
(
    id LONG PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT
);

CREATE TABLE table3
(
    id LONG PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
    t1_id LONG,
    t2_id LONG
);

ALTER TABLE table3
    ADD FOREIGN KEY (t1_id) REFERENCES table1 (id),
    ADD FOREIGN KEY (t2_id) REFERENCES table2 (id);
```

Causes:

```
SQL State  : 42000
Error Code : 42000
Message    : Syntax error in SQL statement "ALTER TABLE TABLE3
    ADD FOREIGN KEY (T1_ID) REFERENCES TABLE1 (ID),[*]
    ADD FOREIGN KEY (T2_ID) REFERENCES TABLE2 (ID)"; SQL statement:
ALTER TABLE table3
    ADD FOREIGN KEY (t1_id) REFERENCES table1 (id),
    ADD FOREIGN KEY (t2_id) REFERENCES table2 (id) [42000-200]
Location   : db/migration/V1_0__init.sql ...V1_0__init.sql)
Line       : 18
Statement  : ALTER TABLE table3
    ADD FOREIGN KEY (t1_id) REFERENCES table1 (id),
    ADD FOREIGN KEY (t2_id) REFERENCES table2 (id)
```

In testing, the following two scenarios are successful though..

```
-- Only 1 foreign key
ALTER TABLE table3
    ADD FOREIGN KEY (t1_id) REFERENCES table1 (id);

-- Inlined foreign keys in table creation
CREATE TABLE table3
(
    id LONG PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
    t1_id LONG,
    t2_id LONG,

    FOREIGN KEY (t1_id) REFERENCES table1 (id),
    FOREIGN KEY (t2_id) REFERENCES table2 (id)
);
```

Is there a limitation in H2 to add multiple foreign keys at the same time?

Comment: Not sure, but will try to help. Does `id` need to be the same as, in this case, `t1_id`? https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_foreignkey.asp

Comment: and by your last bit of code, table 3 isn't created by the time you are altering it?

Comment: @Mech - Sorry- it was created, just tried to provide examples of other things I tried and worked in comparison. The accepted answer seems to be spot on in my testing between this and PostgreSQL

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not a limitation of H2. In the SQL Standard you can't define multiple constraints at once in the `ALTER TABLE` statement, you can define them all at once only in the definition of the table. If they weren't already defined in the `CREATE TABLE` command, you need to use two separate `ALTER TABLE` commands:

```sql
ALTER TABLE table3
    ADD FOREIGN KEY (t1_id) REFERENCES table1 (id);
ALTER TABLE table3
    ADD FOREIGN KEY (t2_id) REFERENCES table2 (id)
```

Some databases, such as MySQL, have their own vendor-specific syntax, but such syntax is not compatible with other databases, including the H2 (even in MySQL compatibility mode).

Comment: Makes sense! I searched high and low for a reasoning on why it'd work on MYSQL and not H2. So now I'm at an impasse at getting these existing flyway scripts to populate the H2 database for testing. JPA creates them differently (many-to-many's and one-to-many's it seems) but validates fine against what flyway produces.